# for..in loop & Object.keys different behavior

Tags: javascript

I have this object function constructor:

```
const Shape = function(name){
this.name = name;
}
Shape.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
```

and I have this instance

```
const square = new Shape("square");
```

When I use for loop to iterate over the square object I can see that the iteration process is being happen over the prototype of the square object

```
for (const key in square) console.log(key);
/* #output:
name
getName
*/
```

but when I use the Object.keys() function I can see that the iteration process is not iterating over the prototype object

```
/* #output:
["name"]
*/
```

What is the behind the scenes reason for that?

Here is what I've tried:

I've tried to console.log the descriptor of the getName method from the prototype object, I've seen that the enumerable attribute is set to true by default:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(square), "getName"))

/* #output:
configurable: true
enumerable: true
value: ƒ ()
writable: true
__proto__: Object
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.keys` only iterates over *enumerable own* properties. In contrast, `for..in` iterates over all enumerable properties anywhere on the object's prototype chain.

With this code:

```
const Shape = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Shape.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
```

A `Shape` instance is receiving an own property of a `name`, so it gets iterated over by both iteration methods. In contrast, `getName` is on an instance's *prototype* - it's not a property of the instance itself, so it isn't returned in `Object.keys`:

```js
const Shape = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Shape.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
const square = new Shape("square");
console.log(
  square.hasOwnProperty('name'),
  square.hasOwnProperty('getName'),
  Shape.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getName')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the behind the scenes reason for that?

[`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops through **all** of the string-named enumerable properties in the object, including inherited ones.

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only gives you an array of the object's **own** (non-inherited) string-named enumerable properties. Just for illustration, it's similar to:

```
// Rough, not-exact-in-every-detail implementation of `Object.keys`
// in terms of `for-in`
const result = [];
for (const name in object) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, name)) {
        result.push(name);
    }
}
```

There's also [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) which gives you an array of all of the objects's own string-named properties (even the non-enumerable ones), and [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) which gives you an array of the object's own Symbol-named properties (even the non-enumerable ones). (There's no Symbol equivalent of `Object.keys`.)

---

> I've tried to console.log the descriptor of the getName method from the prototype object, I've seen that the enumerable attribute is set to true by default:

It is when you create the property via assignment as you do in your question. If you create the property via `Object.defineProperty`, or by using method syntax in a `class` construct, `enumerable` defaults to `false`.

Examples:

```js
// Your original code:
const Shape = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Shape.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
showFlag(Shape.prototype, "getName");       // true

// Using `Object.defineProperty`:
const Shape2 = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Object.defineProperty(Shape2.prototype, "getName", {
    value: function(){
        return this.name;
    },
    writable: true,     // These also default to `false`, but you
    configurable: true  // usually want them to be `true` for methods
});
showFlag(Shape2.prototype, "getName");      // false 

// Using `class` syntax
class Shape3 {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
showFlag(Shape3.prototype, "getName");      // false


function showFlag(proto, name) {
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, name).enumerable);
}
```